# Extracting raw value of a Error enum case

Tags: swift, error-handling, enums

I have created a `Result` enum to propagate the result of a `REST API` call.

```
enum Result {
    case success([AnyObject])
    case failure(APIError)
}
```

I also have a `Error` enum to handler errors

```
enum APIError: Error {
    case requestFailed(String)
    case invalidData(String)
    case invalidQuery(String)
    case invalidURL(String)
}
```

I send the error in a completion closure like

```
completion(.failure(.invalidURL("Invalid URL")))
```

How can I access this string in a `if case` scenario?

I am trying to do something like

```
if case .failure(let res) = result /*, case res.invalidQuery(let invalid) */ {
    print(res)
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is having two cases on the same line, you can do it like so:

```
if case .failure(let error) = result, case .invalidQuery(let message) = error {
    print(message)
}
```